# Div animated with jQuery behind a element

Tags: jquery, animation

When  animation play it is positioning over  element and users can´t click in link page.

How I can fix it?

http://yizztech.com/navbar/ (Example and full code here)

Answer (score 1):

```
.yizzbar > ul > li > span > a{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
.yizzbar .bkhover{
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ohgodwhy, not found. Already exists nav.yizzbar > ul div.bkhover{
    background: url('../images/bkhover.png') repeat-x;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
} // nav.yizzbar a{
    padding: 0 1em;
    z-index: 2000;
}

Comment: @Dani What's not found? What's completely fine when I target the elements in the console for me.

Comment: Ohgodwhy when I try click in <a> element, div.bkhover is over and I cant.

Comment: Simply add the styles I've pointed out above into what you've shown here.

Comment: Simply add `display:block;` and `position:relative;` to the `nav.yizzbar a{}`

Comment: Yes... I did in localhost, but not found, I think problem is in absolute position of div.bkhover, but is necesary to correct effect behaviur.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29467/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-dani)

Comment: do you have a local copy of the background image and made sure the path is correct? That would explain the 'not found'

Comment: Solved it. I only needed nav.yizzbar > ul > li > span > a{
    position:relative;
}. Thank you Ohgodwhy!

Answer (score 0):

What about rendering the div before the a link

```
<span>
  <div class="bkhover" style="top: 80px; width: 79px; opacity: 1; height: 32px;"></div>
  <a href="./">Primera</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Hi Oliver, not found, before I have put in this order. Is the same.